# Display a string in tmux status depending on output of command

Tags: tmux

I want the name of a program (a string, not the actual name) to show up in the tmux status bar if that program is running.

This is what i have in my `set -g status-right`:

```
#{?#{!=:#(getPid p),0},program,}
```

Where:

- `#(getPid p)` is the script i'm running, which returns 0 if the program is not running or not 0 (a PID or wc -l) otherwise
- `#{!=:#(getPid p),program,}` should return 1 or 0 depending on the result of the previous step
- `#{?#{!=:#(getPid p),0},program,}` should print "program" if the previous step returns 1

But i can't even print 1 or 0 with just the first step `#{!=:#(getPid p),0}`.
I'm not sure if this is supported, maybe only `#{}` flags are supported on conditionals, not `#()`

**EDIT**

I'm down to `#(getPid p | awk '$0 != 0 {print \"program\"}')` which seems simpler, but still a no go.

**EDIT**

Another approach that also works on the command-line: `if [ $(getPid b) != 0 ]; then echo program; fi`, still nothing on the status bar.

**EDIT**

I decided to make my script echo the program name, so all i need is `#(getPid p)`, but still no go. I think the problem is probably elsewhere. This is the full line:

```
set -g status-right "#(getName p) |#[fg=colour239,bg=colour236,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]#[fg=colour253,bg=colour239] %Y-%m-%d | %H:%M #[fg=colour103,bg=colour239,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]#[fg=colour236,bg=colour103]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, my `getName` script must `echo -n` instead, but of course there's the refresh matter.